# PMD find annotation and check if has attribute

Tags: java, xpath, pmd

How do I write PMD rule which will search for `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` annotation and validate if it has message attribute?

**Bad:**

```
@NotNull
private int value;
```

**Good**

```
@NotNull(message = "value cannot be null.")
private int value;
```

Main concern for me is that this annotation can be placed basicaly anywhere

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the xpath query to find NotNull annotations without a message:
`//Annotation[*/Name/@Image = 'NotNull' and not(.//MemberValuePair/@Image = 'message')]`

I've tested all cases except for ANNOTATION_TYPE, which I'm not sure how to test in the PMD builder app.

If you want all `javax.validation.constraints` I've come up with this:
`//Annotation[*/Name/@Image = tokenize(replace(string-join(//ImportDeclaration/Name/@Image[starts-with(., "javax.validation.constraints.")], "|"), "javax.validation.constraints.", ""), '[|]') and not(.//MemberValuePair/@Image = 'message')]`

So: take all imports that start with `javax.validation.constraints.`, convert to string with `string-join`, remove `javax.validation.constraints.` with `replace` and split back into a set of values with `tokenize`.

Comment: Great! I will check this xpath tomorrow. If I'm not yet asking for too much, could you give an example, how can I modify this xpath so it will look for other annotations from `javax.validation.constraints` package like @AssertTrue or @Min if they also have `message` attribute?

Comment: The brute-force solution would be to `or` them all: `//Annotation[./*/Name[@Image = 'NotNull' or @Image = 'AssertTrue' or ...] and not(.//MemberValuePair/@Image = 'message')]` but with [all the annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html), that will be a bit annoying. PMD has it's own java parser that doesn't know whether or not the used annotation comes from `javax.validation.constraints`. Maybe it would be possible with some very hacky queries on import statements.

Comment: I came up with a pretty crazy query that works for me in pmd designer with XPath 2.0 checked, but please let me know if it also works in the ruleset.

Comment: The second option with 'tokenize' didn't work out. Anyway not every annotation from this package has message attribute so its better that way. THANKS!